# What is the difference between System.Drawing.Point and System.Windows.Point?

Tags: wpf, 2d

1. What's the difference between [`System.Drawing.Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`System.Windows.Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point(v=vs.110).aspx)?
2. In what context should which one be used?

I'm working with WPF.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Point` represents a GDI point and is used in Windows Forms. It can only hold integer values.

WPF doesn't use GDI anymore, so it has its own `System.Windows.Point` type to represents a point, which can have non integer values.

Comment: System.Windows.Point has additional methods like Parse.

Comment: I know this question is old, but thought I would ask. If I want Point functionality, but I am using neither WPF nor Winforms, should I roll my own Point class? Or should I favor one of these two? Or, does it just not matter that much.

Comment: @Sperry, in this case I would create my own class. It takes about 2 minutes, and it avoids adding a reference to an assembly you don't really need.

Comment: Maybe this is just an old answer but since .NET Standard 2.0 the primitive types of `System.Drawing` (including `Point[F]`, `Size[F]`, `Rectangle[F]`, `Color`, etc.) are included in every possible .NET implementations on every platform, and are totally independent from GDI+. The GDI-specific types, such as `Bitmap` are in a separate Windows-only NuGet package `System.Drawing.Common`. So today I would hesitate to recommend duplicating these primitive types in every new custom library... which often ends up creating a bunch of interop methods to still support them eventually.

Answer (score 3):

One is used with the classes in `System.Drawing` namespaces, and one is used with WPF.

The `System.Drawing.Point` is not so surprisingly used with the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespaces. The `System.Windows.Point` is used with WPF.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.