# What is the difference between System.Windows.Point and System.Drawing.Point namespace?

Tags: .net, winforms, namespaces, drawing, delphi-prism

I want to draw a line using controlpaint.DrawReversibleLine method and tried to pass system.windows.point, but it wants system.drawing.point input. I am little confused. What are the differences between them? Or How are they different besides the noticeable differences?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between System.Drawing.Point and System.Windows.Point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659520/what-is-the-difference-between-system-drawing-point-and-system-windows-point)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Windows.Point` is a WPF structure, whereas `System.Drawing.Point` is a WinForms structure.

In general, if you're writing a WinForms app, the *don't* use stuff from any of the `System.Windows` namespaces (except `System.Windows.Forms`). The resources in these namespaces are WPF specific, so unless you intend to interface WPF and WinForms, it would be best to avoid them.

Answer (score 4):

- [`System.Windows.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx) is intended for WPF applications.

  > The System.Windows namespaces contain types used in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications, including animation clients, user interface controls, data binding, and type conversion
- [`System.Drawing.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) is intended for WinForms applications.

  > The System.Drawing namespace provides access to GDI+ basic graphics functionality.