# What is the difference between System.Windows.Size and System.Drawing.Size?

Tags: c#, .net, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between System.Drawing.Point and System.Windows.Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659520/what-is-the-difference-between-system-drawing-point-and-system-windows-point)

Why are there these two different Size structures?
Under what circumstances would you choose to use each of these? I am unclear about how to choose the correct one in my code.

Comment: Check following 2 links which will show you all things.<br/>
[**system.windows.size**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.size.aspx)<br/>
[**system.drawing.size**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx)<br/>
This will give you briefly knowledge....

Comment: According to the `Levenshtein Distance` it's 7.

Comment: @ValtasarIII - not a dupe, since Size and Point are different types. Perhaps the answer is the same reason, but people won't necessarily know this.

Comment: They are different types that happen to have the same name and some similar logical aspects. They are not interchangeable. The correct one depends on what you wish to achieve, I can not envisage a sensible scenariao where they are both viable options.

Answer (score 10):

`System.Drawing.Size` is part of GDI+.
`System.Windows.Size` is part of WPF.

The most noticable difference is that `System.Drawing.Size` uses `int`s for its width and height fields, while the `System.Windows.Size` uses `double`s.

This stems from the fact that the WPF layout framework is vector based and not raster based like GDI+.

You choose one or the other depending on the UI framework you are using.

Answer (score 3):

These are diferent data types, referenced in different assemblies for different target of progects.

`System.Windows.Size`:  you will find in `WPF`

`System.Drawing.Size` : you will find in `Windows Forms`

Comment: This helps a lot, especially after the previous answer. I hadn't noticed the differing units. Thanks!