# I need help converting System.Window.Size to System.Window.Point

Tags: wpf, vb.net, printing

I just started working on an existing VB project where the end user wants the ability to print a WPF window as a full page to a printer. I found this code sample in C# and it worked just fine in C#

[Printing WPF Window to Printer and Fit on a Page](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11903/printing-wpf-window-to-printer-and-fit-on-a-page.aspx)

However when I tried converting it to VB I am getting two errors

1. System.Drawing.Size cannot be converted to System.Windows.Size
2. System.Drawing.Point cannot be converted to System.Windows.Point

I sort of know what the difference in Drawing.Size and Windows.Size is based on this (and a couple of other) SO threads [What is the difference between System.Drawing.Point and System.Windows.Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659520/what-is-the-difference-between-system-drawing-point-and-system-windows-point) but I cannot figure out how to modify my translation in a way that I can make the conversion happen in VB the way it works on C#. The errors appear on the Measure(sz) and the Arrange(new Rect(.....) lines.

What do I need to do to make this work?

```
Private Sub PrintWindow()
    Dim printDlg As PrintDialog = New PrintDialog()

    If printDlg.ShowDialog() = True Then

        Dim capabilities As System.Printing.PrintCapabilities =
            printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket)

        Dim scale As Double = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / ActualWidth,
                                       capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight / ActualHeight)

        LayoutTransform = New ScaleTransform(scale, scale)

        Dim sz As New Size(CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth),
                           CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight))

        Measure(sz)

        Arrange(New Rect(New Point(CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth),
                                   CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight)), sz))

        printDlg.PrintVisual(Me, "First Fit to Page WPF Print")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do something like this ?

```
    Dim sz As New System.Windows.Size(CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth),
                       CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight))


    Arrange(New Rect(New System.Windows.Point(CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth),
                               CInt(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight)), sz))
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it but I am still working on understanding the original problem and how this fixed it. Anyway thanks. Your suggestion made the compiler happy.

Comment: The Mesure and Arrange methods needed different types , 
System.Windows.Size is different from System.Drawing.Size  
What's not to understand.